# Can the location of a cellphone be pin-pointed?

Tags: mobile, geolocation, simcard

If a person uses a SIM card that is pre-rica registered (meaning it is not registered on his name but the supplier), can you pin-point where a particular message or call was made from? For example: the person was at 2 Simon street @ 18:00 on 5 September2015 when the making the call or sending the message.

Answer (score 4):

> .. can you pin-point ...

This depends who 'you' are and how exact you need the location.
A mobile phone needs to connect to a nearby base station in order to send the message. Each base station can serve a number of users in parallel and also has a limited reach, which is even more limited in cities because of all the buildings. If you know which base station the phone is connected to you can tell the area where the phone currently is (accuracy can be 50m in cities).

The operator of the network does know which mobile phone is connected to which base station. It will also store these information for a while and will usually provide law enforcement with this information. But as a normal user you don't get access to these information.

For more information see [wikipedia:mobile phone tracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phone_tracking).

Comment: Triangulation from 3 or more towers in a cellphone network can pinpoint the location of a phone, it was used in an emergency here to find a driver who got lost on some BLM backroads. Coordination between SAR, the local Sheriff's department and the cellphone provider used the connection information to establish an area to search.